# Pandas: how to make pivot table with new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table from several files with the same names, but different values:

[image: Table 1]

I need to make new columns, based on the number of repeating names with the saved number of participants, so it looks like this:

[image: Table 2]

I tried to make the pivot table without division of points using

```
df.pivot(index='Name', columns='numbers of participants')
```

But I got an error.

Is it possible to make new columns using the pivot table function?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and pass to [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'numbers of participants']).cumcount().add(1)
df1 = (df.pivot(index=['Name','numbers of participants'], columns='g', values='points')
         .add_prefix('points_')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df1)
  Name  numbers of participants  points_1  points_2
0    A                       20      7679       124
1    B                       30        23       231
2    C                       40       341      4124
```

---

```
df1['numbers of participants'] = df1.pop('numbers of participants')
print (df1)
  Name  points_1  points_2  numbers of participants
0    A      7679       124                       20
1    B        23       231                       30
2    C       341      4124                       40
```

Comment: Thank You for letting know about this function :)
Could you please also help with the following error:
"Length of passed values is 15, index implies 2"

Why can it appear?

Comment: @Ksenia - One idea - What is your pandas version? Is possible upgrade to last?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version.

Comment: @Ksenia I cannot reproduce, problem is with this sample data?